# How do I switch to a worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've already [asked](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/a0579fb8-70ca-4a00-b7b8-5d45af7bc626/) this question in MSDN

How do I switch from the Visual Basic Editor to a worksheet **during runtime**?

If the procedure were *not* running, I could click the View Microsoft Excel button (Alt+F11). Is there a VBA statement that does the same thing?

Thanks,
Shane.

Excel 2010 SP2 (14.0.7173.5000) 64-bit

Comment: I see what you're saying, not sure this is possible. I originally suggested the `Activate` method but that won't make the Excel Window appear. Can you run the method from a button form which would in effect do the same thing (and alternate between worksheets if need be using the `Activate` method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'll annoy you by repeating what you got from MSDN ;). Then I'll describe what ways I found to bring windows to the front.

I too don't see the need to do what you ask. You want to debug your code but for debugging I find it essential (most of the time) to see the code while executing it. Putting the windows side by side and using F8 to step through the code seems like a better option.

For the few scenarios I can think of it would be enough to start the macro from the Excel window (Alt + F8).

---

Now for the actual answer:
I don't know about other versions but for me just activating a window doesn't bring it to the front (Office 2016, Windows 10). I found the following to work:

- Using appactivate (probably the best method although I don't like specifying windows by their name)

  ```
  AppActivate Application.Caption
  ```
- Send keys `Alt` + `F11`:

  ```
  Application.SendKeys "%{F11}"
  ```

  however you should probably check if the excel window is already in front (or you might bring back the VBE). The only way I found was using the system API:

  ```
  'on top of your module
  Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

  'in your sub
  If GetForegroundWindow = Application.VBE.mainwindow.hwnd Then Application.SendKeys "%{F11}"
  ```
- Using system API

  ```
  'on top of your module
  Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

  'in your sub
  SetForegroundWindow ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).hwnd
  ```
- Setting the visibility to false and true again also brings it to the front for me

  ```
  ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
  ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
  ```

Comment: I'm really sorry for taking so long to reply.

I've tried all of your suggestions, and the only thing that works is this:

Application.SendKeys "%{F11}"

As mentioned, if the Excel window is already in front, it will take me to the VBE, but I was only going to use it for debugging any way. So this will do what I need.

Thanks for the help.

Shane.

Answer (score 3):

To display the VBE:

```
Sub ShowVBE()
    With Application.VBE.MainWindow
        .Visible = True
        .SetFocus
    End With
End Sub
```

To activate a Workbook Window, do something like:

```
Sub ShowThisWorkbook()
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Activate
        .Windows(1).Activate
        .Windows(1).WindowState = xlMaximized
        .Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate ' <-- Change to your desired Worksheet name here
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Activating the workbook or workbook window doesn't bring it to the front for me (Office 2016)

Comment: @arcadeprecinct See Edit of my code for `ShowThisWorkbook()`, I should have include the worksheet activate line. Also added to enforce the WindowState as Maximized.